# vagrantfileで1つのipアドレスに複数のゲストとホストを設定するには？

Tags: python, python3, vagrant, virtualbox, jupyter-notebook

**環境**
macbookにvagrantをインストールさせてその中でubuntu14.04を動作している。

**症状**
jupyter noteをvagrantで動作させているのですがサーバーを立ち上げた時に出てくるurlをコピーしてMac側のブラウザーで開いてもアクセスできません。

**やったこと**
最初、jupyterが8888で立ち上がっているのを確認し他のアプリを作った時に使用していた番号が9000だったのでvagrantfileに以下の文を追加したのですが`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888`うまく動作しませんでした。
じゃあ`config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000`を消して変えたらいいのではと思うのですが、これは他のアプリで使いたいので残しておきたいです。

**解決したいこと**
ひとつのipアドレスで複数のゲストとホスト番号を使用したいのですが、このようなことは可能でしょうか？
可能な場合どのようにvagrantfileを変更したらよろしいでしょうか？
jupyter noteのデフォルトアドレスを変更する方法もあるかと思います。
そのやり方も教えて下さるとても助かります。よろしくお願いします。

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  #ここで公式サイトからOSのイメージをダウンロードしている。 
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8888, host: 8888

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.22.41"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/home/vagrant"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.

end
```

Comment: 設定自体には問題がないように見えます。

Comment: 誤って送信した上に5分以上たってしまいました…  
続き  
  
とりあえず、ホストOSのブラウザから  
http://localhost:8888/でつながりますでしょうか？  
  
jupyter noteは使ったことがないのですが、  
> jupyter noteをvagrantで動作させているのですがサーバーを立ち上げた時に出てくるurl  
こちらはjupyter noteを起動したときにjupyter noteが表示するのでしょうか？  
もしそうなら、現在の設定ではVMはprivate_networkとforwarded_portなので、  
当然jupyter noteは内部用のIPを表示するはずです。  
ので、ホストOSや外部からそのIPを使用しようとしても当然つながりません。  
  
forwarded_portは、「ホストOSに来た特定のportへのアクセスを、ゲストOSの特定のportに転送する」設定ですから、  
ホストOSやその外からアクセスする場合は  
http://<ホストIP>:<host:に指定したport>/  
http://localhost:<host:に指定したport>/  
などになります。<br />
（ホストOSのブラウザからなら、localhostでもアクセス可能

Comment: アドレスはjupyter noteから出てくるものです。ブラウザに入力するlocalhostの部分を192.168.22.41に変えるという事でしょうか？

Comment: https://qiita.com/ciela/items/0e0392f600c92b93d7c6

Comment: 上記の記事を参考にやったらできたのですが、IPを0.0.0.0にすることは同じルータ内なら誰でもアクセスできるということでセキュリティ的に少し不安なのですが何か他に良い手はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

状況把握しました。
jupyter note自体が、特定のIP以外を拒否するc.NotebookApp.ipという設定があるのですね。
制限しつつ公開するには、以下のようなものが考えられます。

【方針1】
jupyter noteのc.NotebookApp.ipにホストPCのローカルIPを設定する。

【方針2】
VMのiptables/firewalldなどで、許可するIPをホストPCのみに絞る。

【方針3】
jupyter noteパスワード機能を有効にする
https://qiita.com/SaitoTsutomu/items/aee41edf1a990cad5be6

※　方針１や方針２でうまくいかない場合は
vagrantをpublic_networkにして見てください。
ただし、これをするとVMのIPさえ知っていれば社内LANから自由にアクセスできます。
（VMがLANに直接所属するシンプルなネットワーク構成になる。）